# Is Cassandra database row size limited by available memory?

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra

I'm working with very long time series -- hundreds of millions of data points in one series -- and am considering Cassandra as a data store. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212279/cassandra-time-series-data), one of the Cassandra committers (the über helpful [jbellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130168/jbellis)) says that Cassandra rows can be very large, and that column slicing operations are faster than row slices, hence my question: Is the row size [still limited](http://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/b0c1d8d60372894b6c6443bfaf9a32949e4ffc0e/BUGS.txt) by available memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, row size is still limited by available memory. This is because the compaction algorithm today de-serializes the entire row in memory before writing out the compacted SSTable.

This is currently aimed to be fixed in the 0.7 release. See [CASSANDRA-16](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16) for progress.

Another interesting link: [CassandraLimitations](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations)

Comment: NB. this is fixed now a days. (In the 0.7 release)